# CentOS php fopen permission denied error

Tags: php, centos, fopen, permissions

I am not very familiar with CentOS and its specific permissions issues with httpd+php environment so that I got stuck with "failed to open stream: Permission denied" after installing website on production server.

I have directory layout like that

/usr/local/project
...
/usr/local/project/../../public

/var/www/html -> /usr/local/project/../../public
   ^
symlink

Script tries to write to project's sub directory and gets permission denied error.

I have tried

1) set 744 permissions for this folder
2) set 777 for entire project's tree
3) set open_basedir to /usr/local/project in combination with previous permissions changing

Nothing helped.

What can cause permissions error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you have SELinux enabled? If yes then disable it

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/switch-off-selinux-centos-5/

Comment: thx, it solved problem

Comment: Hi, still at 2016, on Redhat Enterpise 7, this is true and useful.